# Jquery scrollTop not working in "proceed" section

Tags: jquery, scrolltop

I have the following Jquery which fires if I put them in one of the "validation if blocks" but not working if I put it in "else"section of proceed validation.

Any idea how to fix it? I don't want to put scrolltop action to all field validation if block.

Here is my code:

```
if(location=="-"){ 
            $('select[name=location2]').css('border-color','red'); 
            proceed = false;
        }
        if(resort==""){ 
            $('select[name=sublocation2]').css('border-color','red'); 
            proceed = false;
        }
        if(price==""){ 
            $('input[name=price]').css('border-color','red'); 
            proceed = false;
        }
        if(user_password2==""){ 
            $('input[name=pass2]').css('border-color','red'); 
            proceed = false;
        }
        if(user_regtype==""){ 
            $('select[name=regtype]').css('border-color','red'); 
            proceed = false;
        }
        if(user_name==""){ 
            $('input[name=name]').css('border-color','red'); 
            proceed = false;
        }
        if(user_phone=="") {    
            $('input[name=phone]').css('border-color','red');
            proceed = false;
        }
        if(user_mobile=="") {    
            $('input[name=mobile]').css('border-color','red');
            proceed = false;
        }
        if(imageverification=="") {  
            $('input[name=verifyimage]').css('border-color','red'); 
            proceed = false;
        }

        //everything looks good! proceed...
        if(proceed) 
        {
            //data to be sent to server
            post_data = {'location':location, 'sublocation':user_email2, 'propertytype':password, 'description':description, 'bedrooms':bedrooms, 'bathrooms':bathrooms, 'balconies':balconies, 'propertysize':propertysize, 'plotsize':plotsize, 'swimmingpool':swimmingpool, 'resortcenter':resortcenter, 'resortcentertype':resortcentertype, 'busroutes':busroutes, 'busroutestype':busroutestype, 'supermarket':supermarket, 'supermarkettype':supermarkettype, 'restaurant':restaurant, 'restauranttype':restauranttype, 'nearestbeach':nearestbeach, 'nearestbeachtype':nearestbeachtype, 'lstBox2':lstBox2, 'lstBox4':lstBox4, 'lstBox6':lstBox6};

            //Ajax post data to server
            $.post('addproperty.php', post_data, function(response){  

                //load json data from server and output message     
                if(response.type == 'error')
                {
                    output = '<div class="error">'+response.text+'</div>';
                    refresh_image();
                }else{

                    output = '<div class="success">'+response.text+'</div>';

                    //reset values in all input fields
                    $('#propadd_form input').val(''); 
                    $('#propadd_form textarea').val('');
                }

                $("#result3").hide().html(output).slideDown();
            }, 'json');

        } else {
            $("html, body").delay(1000).animate({scrollTop: $('#headadd').offset().top }, 1000);
            $("#result3").html('<div class="error">All highlighted fields must be filled or selected</div>');
            //refresh_image();
        }
    });
```

Comment: How about making fiddle???

Comment: Manwal I don't have any idea what a Fiddle is sorry.

Comment: Go to [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/). Use your code.

Comment: no need to do that. when I move the line starts with "$("html, body").delay(1000)..." to one of the "if ... empty" checks it works. What I need is the scroll triggered once if the submit is false.